# Remove specific value from .txt file while using (readtable) MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am running into an issue while using the readtable function on a *TSPLIB .txt* file in **MATLAB**. I have searched for a solution to this problem, but my problem seems to be different from other problems.

The problem is that every *.txt* file I am trying to import ends with '`EOF`' as the last 3 characters. When I manually remove this value from the *.txt* file, readtable does exactly what I want by creating a table from the values in the file. I am using the following code to read the files, but this code will not work when '`EOF`' still is in the file:

```
data = readtable('d493.txt', 'HeaderLines', 6, 'Format', '%f %f %f')
```

How can I use code to remove the '`EOF`' from each file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple option is to utilize the [`'CommentStyle'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#input_argument_namevalue_d119e888298) option of [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) to treat lines that start with `'EOF'` as comments and ignore them.

For example, with the following `asdf.txt`:

```
header1, header2
123, 456
789, 123
EOF
```

We can load in our file with `readtable`, as desired:

```
>> test = readtable('asdf.txt', 'CommentStyle', 'EOF')

test =

  2×2 table

    header1    header2
    _______    _______

    123        456    
    789        123
```